# MVC3 Razor Engine, grabbing data from a form to redirect to the showpage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I need help, I'm trying to fill a List containing models

The list should consist of n number of this model.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Fraværsregistrering_1.Models
{
    public class FraværsseddelModel
    {
        public int Lovligt { get; set; }
        public int Ulovligt { get; set; }
    }
}
```

What I have done so far is that I have a controller for looking at data it looks like this:

```
using Fraværsregistrering_1.Helpers;
using Fraværsregistrering_1.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Fraværsregistrering_1.Controllers
{
    public class fraværController : Controller
    {

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<FraværsseddelModel> objList = Fraværsliste.getFraværssedler();
            return View(objList);
        }

        public ActionResult Anmeld()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(FraværsseddelModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("index");
            }
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I call a helperclass, and it is clear that I want to put something in a list so that I can use it:

```
using Fraværsregistrering_1.Helpers;
using Fraværsregistrering_1.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Fraværsregistrering_1.Helpers
{
    public class Fraværsliste
    {
        private static List<FraværsseddelModel> list = new List<FraværsseddelModel>();
        public static List<FraværsseddelModel> getFraværssedler(FraværsseddelModel m)
        {
            list.Add(m);
            return list;
        }
        public static List<FraværsseddelModel> getFraværssedler()
        {
            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

my biggest problem here is that I don't know how to extract the model, I want to use for the method getFraværssedler(FraværsseddelModel m), from the View which looks this way:

```
@model Fraværsregistrering_1.Models.FraværsseddelModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Anmeld";
}

<h2>Anmeld nyt fravær</h2>

<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
    <pre>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Lovligt)  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Lovligt)
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Ulovligt) @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Ulovligt)
    </pre>
    <input type="submit" value="Anmeld" />
    }
</div>
```

I'm not quite sure what the submit-input does exactly... But I know that I can't seem to find the values I want...

the last thing I'm trying to do is to redirect after submitting the form for a "fraværsseddel" to this View:

```
@model List<Fraværsregistrering_1.Models.FraværsseddelModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Mit fravær";
}

<h2>Mit fravær</h2>

<div>
    <table border="0">
        @foreach (Fraværsregistrering_1.Models.FraværsseddelModel seddel in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Fraværsseddel</strong></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Lovligt fravær:</td>
                <td>@seddel.Lovligt</td>
                <td>timer</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ulovligt fravær:</td>
                <td>@seddel.Ulovligt</td>
                <td>timer</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="button" value="Anmeld nyt fravær" onclick="window.location.href='/fravær/anmeld'" />
</div>
```

Comment: Just a recommendation, just change the "æ" character for an "a" or "e", in order to be easier to read. On the other hand can you be more specific on what you want to do, or what the problem is?

Comment: oh sry I want to take the recorded data from the form in @Viewbag.Title = "Anmeld", to create an object that I can put in the parametized constructor in Fravaerliste.cs

Comment: I think you should read this tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3 It explains how to save and retrieve data in a MVC-3 application. Also keep in mind that MVC-4 and 5 have been released. Let me know